# Find distinct values as per condition in MYSQL and count for the resul in next column PHP

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I am trying to find a MySQL query that will first find distinct values for a month in a particular field and then count count the number of occurrences of that value in other field and display the result in PHP MySQL

example db

```
id        Month        task completed   
====================================
vc        02             Yes
vd        02             Yes 
ve        02             Yes
vc        02             Yes
vc        03             Yes
vd        03             No
ve        03             Yes
```

expected result

```
Month: 02

id count of task competed
-------------------------
vc         2
vd         1 
ve         1
```

Also there are 100s of ids so specifying one by one is not an option

Comment: $res=@mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT Id FROM tablename WHERE        MONTH(Date)=$month;");

    $task=@mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(task) AS quant  FROM tablename WHERE   MONTH(Date)=$month AND task='yes'AND  Id ='vc'");
   while($row1=@mysql_fetch_array($res) AND $row2=@mysql_fetch_array($lmpr))

  {
  /* echo output*/
  }

Comment: please do not encourage the use of `mysql_*` API; it has been removed from the latest version of PHP.  Instead, use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*)
    FROM tbl
    WHERE month = '02'
      AND task_completed = 'Yes'
    GROUP BY id;
```